# Is there any Raspberry Pi version of sagemath?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, education

Is there any Raspberry Pi version of `sagemath`? Or is it possible to port `sagemath` anyway to use it on Raspberry Pi? By the way, I have the Raspberry Pi 3B board with 32 bit Raspbian Jessie on it.

Comment: You should also delete your outdated comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sage version 6.9 for 12.10 Ubuntu arm available through http://mirrors.mit.edu/sage/linux/arm/meta/sage-6.9-armv7l-Linux-Ubuntu_12.10.tar.gz.torrent works perfectly on Pi 3B board with 32 bit Raspbian Jessie desktop. Just extract that downloaded tar.gz file into RPI's home directory and give executable permission to the binary file "sage" by `$ sudo chmod +x sage` and then launch the program by `$ ./sage` in terminal and there it goes, a fully working sage interface.[image]

Comment: and direct link https://drive.google.com/open?id=13cqZCclqSXOm0D5kxQExQS9eZY-87uGr

Comment: Yay, sagemath is now available on the raspbian stretch & buster repo.

Answer (score 2):

Current Raspbian (based on Debian Buster distro) has SageMath version 8.6
available.

So yes, it has been ported to Debian, adn this port allowed it to run on Raspberry Pi. Current development vesrions of Sagemath can be built on Pi 4 with 8Gb of RAM, I don't know whether this is possible on less powerful models.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.19.118-v7l+ #1311 SMP Mon Apr 27 14:26:42 BST 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sage
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ SageMath version 8.6, Release Date: 2019-01-15                     │
│ Using Python 2.7.16. Type "help()" for help.                       │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

As one can see:

```
$ apt list | grep sagemath

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

sagemath-common/stable,now 8.6-6 all [installed,automatic]
sagemath-database-conway-polynomials/stable,now 0.5-4 all [installed,automatic]
sagemath-database-elliptic-curves/stable,now 0.8-2 all [installed,automatic]
sagemath-database-graphs/stable,now 20161026+dfsg-2 all [installed,automatic]
sagemath-database-mutually-combinatorial-designs/stable,now 20140630-3 all [installed,automatic]
sagemath-database-polytopes/stable,now 20170220-2 all [installed,automatic]
sagemath-doc-ca/stable 8.6-6 all
sagemath-doc-de/stable 8.6-6 all
sagemath-doc-en/stable,now 8.6-6 all [installed,automatic]
sagemath-doc-es/stable 8.6-6 all
sagemath-doc-fr/stable 8.6-6 all
sagemath-doc-hu/stable 8.6-6 all
sagemath-doc-it/stable 8.6-6 all
sagemath-doc-ja/stable 8.6-6 all
sagemath-doc-pt/stable 8.6-6 all
sagemath-doc-ru/stable 8.6-6 all
sagemath-doc-tr/stable 8.6-6 all
sagemath-jupyter/stable,now 8.6-6 all [installed,automatic]
sagemath/stable,now 8.6-6 armhf [installed]
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/96645)

Comment: The question was whether such a version exists. Yes, it does, that's what my answer says.

Answer (score 1):

The Raspbian Jessie repositories do not have a usable version of `sagemath`. The packages that look as if they might be seem to be ancient support packages from 2012, but the main system itself is missing.

While it does look technically possible to compile sagemath under Raspbian (given a couple of days + plenty of additional swap space), it doesn't look as if many people have tried it since Mathematica 10 became available.